# How to store and retrieve chinese characters in oracle

Tags: oracle, oracle11g, oracle10g

I have a requirement to store Chinese characters in DB.
I tried doing the same, referring info available stackoverflow but couldnot succeed.

Please help me out if I am missing something.

I created a table :

```
 create table test_chinese_characters(col1 varchar2(50),col2 nvarchar2(50));
```

fired an insert statement :

```
insert into test_chinese_characters(col1,col2) values('漢','漢');
```

The data that I can see in DB : something weird. How can I see the chinese characters as it is when I store or retrieve the same.

```
NLS_parameters details :
NLS_CHARACTERSET =  WE8ISO8859P1
NLS_NCHAR_CHARACTERSET = UTF8
```

Dump function on the above columns of test table resulted in :

```
col1 :  Typ=1 Len=1: 191 
col2 :  Typ=1 Len=2: 194,191
```

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: What is your NLS_LANG setting?

Comment: NLS_LANGUAGE :AMERICAN

Comment: Try setting NLS_LANG as CHINESE_CHINA.WE8ISO8859P1

Comment: @Anshoo You'll probably have to make changes to your registry. Here's a good read. http://www.dba-oracle.com/t_storing_chinese_character_set.htm

Comment: What If I do not want to change the nls lang param( i have a common table to store data of other languages as well.) Is their any value that I can provide against NLS_LANGUAGEE which can take care of all the languages?

Answer (score 0):

You can try setting your `NLS_LANG` to `CHINESE_CHINA.WE8ISO8859P1`.

If you want to do from code level, try like below:

```
Environment.SetEnvironmentVariable("NLS_LANG", "CHINESE_CHINA.WE8ISO8859P1", EnvironmentVariableTarget.Process)
```